# How do I use tortoisehg authorcolor setting?

Tags: tortoisehg

TortoiseHg has two authorcolor settings

```
[tortoisehg]
authorcolor = True
authorcolor.USERNAME = color
```

1. Is it possible to use the second line without the first?  I will assume not, though I am mainly interested in giving my commits a distinct color.
2. How do I use the specific form?  The only example I have seen is something like `authorcolor.Bob = blue`.  But my 'username', as previously listed earlier in the file, is `Terry Jan Reedy <email@some.place>`.  How do I translate that into a replacement for `USERNAME`.  I have tried various combinations of quotes or not and email or not.  Unfortunately, my default color is a drab green that is one of the least distinguished.  Also, what `color`s can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Two** settings was in the ol' good times of THG 2.0 (kinda "ancient" for 3.8, ya?!). Now I can't find *any* reference to predefined authorcolor **in GUI** (compare state with branch coloring, f.e.). Now, I suppose, they assigned semi-automatically (if enabled) and author-color selection based on (somehow poorly "translated"?) author-string (see sample from repo with just three authors and common /short/ leading part of two).

[image: Authors in THG]

No, you can't use `authorcolor.USERNAME = color` without `authorcolor = True` because default value for authorcolor is `false` with no coloring

2. Author-id in Mercurial can be (theoretically) any, this is free-form field and "Full Username " is just widely accepted convention. When|if you want to use authorcolor.USERNAME, you have to use **full username** as it defined in your `[ui] username =` or in changesets (because [even *single additional space* leading to a string-mismatch](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4316/author-color-should-be-based-on-email))

[image: Names differ]

see colors for "luca" and "dedalus" users on screenshots
Yes, special chars in username **must be** escaped (I found repo with only e-mail in commiter-id, but "authorcolor.email@domain.tld" also failed), maybe we can use escaping rules for branch-names (not tested, too lazy)

PS: Anyway, just for memory I [created ticket](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4512/describe-escaping-rules-for-full-username) for THG, you can support and monitor it, if you want

Comment: 1.a I have authorcolor turned on and it works, except that it gives my name a color that does not stand out.  1.b I copied the setting syntax from section '5.4.14. Configurables' in the 3.6 document opened in Explorer when I click Help => Help.  2.a In CPython repository, everyone uses what must be their full names, or at least an ascii version thereof -- multiple words with spaces. 2.b I have tried my full name, copied from the [ui] username field, both with and without the email part, both with and without a space before '='.  I cannot find a combination that works.  2.c Does this ever work?

Comment: I have also tried ' and " quotes, though I am not sure if that was with email or not.  I also  do not know if change should take effect immediately or if I have to quit and restart, or even reboot.  Should color be capitalized or not?  At this point, there are an impractical number of combination to try.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy - 1b OK, I saw this text also in my "TortoiseHg 3.8.0 documentation" 2b - you **must to use** full name with e-mail (even additional space matter). Color have to be NOT capitalized (I least I see such names in color-array and use such names in template-file). I think, you have (can to try) to encode full string `Terry Jan Reedy <email@some.place>` according to Branch Color rules (without additional unescaped /any/ quotes around) 2c - I don't know, does it work or not

Comment: @TerryJanReedy - about 2c: I couldn't get to work even in toy-repo with just "User" (in form `= colorname` or `= #RGB`): only auto-selected colors, which change, when I change username

Comment: I have tried full string, cut and pasted, with no quotes.  If no one gives a different answer soon, I will accept 'Does not work, hg bug.'  I notice that you allowed for that possibility in issue.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy - without escaping will not work definitely. You have escape at least: spaces, dots(?), @

Comment: What do you mean by 'escaping?  Beginning and end markers, and special prefixes are the main methods, with multiple variations of each.  Putting \ in from of every non-letter also did not work.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy - even plain ASCII firstname doens't work (for me)